# Paypal basic form to pay by credit card without paypal account

Tags: paypal

I am using basic form the allow paypal purchases:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="return" value="http://site.bike.com.au/checkout/paymentSuccess/@Model.UniqueId">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="admin@bike.com.au">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderDetails name" value="Bike">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="@Model.TotalPrice">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name"value="Bike + Delivery">

    <input class="btnPaypal" type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but6.gif" border="0" name="submit" >
</form>
```

I would like to send the customer to paypal with the option to buy without a paypal account.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to not bother customers who are non Paypal account holders with opening a Paypal account (and create a password), you may set your 
'account optional' settings to on.

To see this, log in, go to Profile and click 'My selling preferences', click on Update next to Website preferences - scroll down the screen and find "PayPal Account Optional" section - you can enable/disable PayPal Account optional here.

If you don't see this feature, you may contact our Business Support direct. They can toggle it for you as we here in tech don't have actually
account access.

Also, it's important to remember that guest checkout is not guaranteed for every transaction. PayPal runs a risk check to determine eligibility for guest checkout. There will be times when guest checkout is not available. This is intended. Here are a few things to make sure guest checkout is offered as often as possible.

- Verified PayPal account
- Confirmed email address
- Guest Checkout enabled

If all of these are met and it's not available then our system has decided to disable the guest checkout option for risk reasons. This is not a permanent decision and it will be available in the future.